# GROUP_CONCAT creates NULL Entry

Tags: mysql

I have an old helpdesk ticketing system that I've been tasked with porting data out of and into our new ticketing system. Here's the query I'm running:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS final_table;

CREATE TABLE final_table (
    name varchar(40), 
    ticketID BIGINT, 
    ticket_id BIGINT,
    subject varchar(255), 
    priority_id varchar(10), 
    status varchar(10), 
    updated DATE, 
    created DATE,
    closed DATE,
    response LONGTEXT
);

ALTER TABLE final_table ADD PRIMARY KEY(ticket_id);

INSERT INTO final_table
SELECT      name, ticketID, ticket_id, subject, priority_id, status, updated, created, closed, response
FROM        ost_ticket;

ALTER TABLE final_table ADD response LONGTEXT;
ALTER TABLE final_table ADD impact varchar(40);
ALTER TABLE final_table ADD category varchar(20);
ALTER TABLE final_table ADD queue varchar (20);

UPDATE final_table SET impact = "1 person can't work";
UPDATE final_table SET category = "Other";
UPDATE final_table SET queue = "Help Desk";

INSERT INTO final_table( response )
SELECT      GROUP_CONCAT(ost_ticket_response.response SEPARATOR "\n\n") AS response
FROM        ost_ticket_response
GROUP BY    ost_ticket_response.ticket_id;
```

The old ticketing software has the PK listed multiple times in the ost_ticket_response table, hence the need for the GROUP_CONCAT call in the last four lines. Basically I'm trying to combine the entries that have the same ticket_id and then pull that into the temp table I'm creating. If I run the query as it stands now, it just populates the response column with null results. Any ideas?

Comment: It shouldn't include `NULL`; but why not just filter out `NULL`s? `WHERE ost_ticket_response.response IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to return a NULL, regardless of what the actual content is. There's only a handful of NULL entries (maybe 4 total) yet this populates that column entirely with NULL data.